# back button- Confirm form resubmission using jsp, servlet and filter

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, servlet-filters

I followed some examples I saw here to write my code but I get a confirm form resubmission when I press the browser back button after logout. I am using two jsp pages, the index page which contains the login form and the welcome page which displays after suuccessful login.
 A login servlet which processes the login data and sets the session atribute and a logout servlet which removes session atribute and invalidate the session.

A filter which checks for session attribute and sets the no-cache...on the browser. all the other aspect works fine but when I press the back button after logout,it displays "confirm form resubmission". please I think am not getting something right. I need help. Thank you.

Comment: Read this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get

Comment: You can't alter the back button behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing `logout` with `post` method? If yes, For `logout` browser sending some data to server, when you press back button brower assumes your trying to reload, and ask you to confirm form submit. It wont be a problem until unless, user `logout` properly other wise you have to check your filters.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. yes am using a post method. is this wrong?